# Retrieve object attribute using a parameter

Tags: javascript, function, object, return-value

I've built a simple object which simulates a table following the answers to this question: [Store a table of data in a JavaScript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471869/store-a-table-of-data-in-a-javascript-variable)

The modeled table is something like this:

```
         | Tension | Dissonance | Modal |
value_a  | 1.234   |  5.324     | 7.24  |
value_b  | 3       | 6.341      | 27.3  |
```

I would like to access and retrieve the `Tension`, `Dissonance` and `Modal` values for a single entry `value_a` (for example), passing to a function the selected parameter.

So far i tried something like this:

```
var myObj = {
    value_a:{D:3.944,T:1.1606,M:5.3893},
    value_b:{D:2,T:6.543,M:5.10},
    myMethod: function(params) {
      console.log(params);
      console.log(this.params); //since this.value_a is a correct expression, i thought this might work, but it doesn't
    }
};
```

I would like to be able to do a call like `myObj.myMethod("value_a")` and then return the value of `[D,T,M]` associated with `value_a`

I tried this way (and i know it doesn't work), but i don't know if it's possible to use a parameter as selector of an attribute.

If not, how could i pass the parameter and return the relative attribute values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) such as `someObject[property_name]`. Inside the brackets would need to be a string or Symbol.

```js
var myObj = {
    value_a: { D:3.944, T:1.1606, M:5.3893 },
    value_b: { D:2, T:6.543, M:5.10 },
    myMethod: function(params) {
      console.log(params);
      console.log(this[params]);
    }
};

myObj.myMethod("value_a");
myObj.myMethod("value_b");
myObj.myMethod("foo"); // undefined
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Works perfectly! Can i ask you why it's different from the dot notation? Are they equivalent? I mean, `myObj.value_a` and `myObj[value_a] ` will behave in the same way?

Comment: They are not equivalent and will not behave in the same way. With bracket notation, the value inside the brackets is evaluated prior to attempting to access that respective object property. If you need to dynamically access object properties, you would use bracket notation.

Comment: So the dot notation is used for (maybe i'm using the term improperly) static elements? If i want to call a fixed variable/method (and i now a priori the name) i'll use `myObj.element`, while if i need to make it dependent by an external parameter, i'll use `myObj[param]` right?

Comment: Sure, it can be seen that way. At a basic level, if you know the exact/static properties you need to access, you can use dot notation or [ES6 object destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring). If you need to access properties dynamically (or externally dependent as you describe), then you can use bracket notation.